# How do I get a specific file using Client Object Model in Silverlight?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, silverlight

I can't seem to find any direction when trying to filter a FileCollection (Picture Library) by a specific value. I am 'trying' to use the Silverlight Client Object Model to access list data in Sharepoint 2010. The code below works but returns a collection of Files that are all the same image/file. I can kind of see why but can't seem to bind the Caml Query to FileCollection.

What would be the best way to Filter this collection. I have thought about LINQ but not that clued up on it.

```
private void MyMethod()
{
   CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
   camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='VersionIssueID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + _versionIssueID + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
   List imageList = Global.GetClientContext().Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Image Library");
   _fileCollection = imageList.RootFolder.Files;
   Global.GetClientContext().Load(_fileCollection);
   Global.GetClientContext().ExecuteQueryAsync(OnQuerySucceededListenerGetImages, onQueryFailed);
}

[Other bits...]

foreach (File li in _fileCollection)
{
   string fileName = _fileCollection[0].Name;
   string fileUrl = Global.GetClientContext().Url + _fileCollection[0].ServerRelativeUrl;

   if ((fileName.EndsWith(".png")) || (fileName.EndsWith(".jpg")))
   {
      Image img = new Image();
      BitmapImage bitMap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
      img.Source = bitMap;

      ImagePanel.Children.Add(img);
   }
}
```

Could I use a LINQ like so:

```
imageList.RootFolder.Files.Where(...)
```

Not to sure what my where clause would be or if this would work.

Anyway if anyone could help me out or point me in the right direction, I would be grateful.

Comment: I think I didn't get what exactly is wrong or what are you trying to do... What is in collection that's returned? And what do you want to be in that collection?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jumbo, the collection returns (in this instance) 37 images, that is how many images I have in my 'Image Library', thing is all 37 images are the same image. Not so in the library though. I am only trying to return a single image and display it. I am probably going wrong with the collection loop. Though I might need to filter collection with LINQ? Not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see a problem in your code snippet - in your `foreach` loop, you iterate through all pictures returned, but you reference only the first picture (`_fileCollection[0]`) in every iteration:

```
foreach (File li in _fileCollection) // <--- you are iterating through whole collection
{
    // but in every iteration,
    string fileName = _fileCollection[0].Name;  // you are referencing just the FIRST picture!!!
    string fileUrl = Global.GetClientContext().Url + _fileCollection[0].ServerRelativeUrl; // same problem here

    // should be
    string fileName = li.Name;  // each time NEW picture!!!
    string fileUrl = Global.GetClientContext().Url + li.ServerRelativeUrl; // same here


    if ((fileName.EndsWith(".png")) || (fileName.EndsWith(".jpg")))
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        BitmapImage bitMap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
        img.Source = bitMap;

        ImagePanel.Children.Add(img);
    }
}
```

But if you need only the first picture, you can use `<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>` inside `<View>` tag of your CamlQuery. Or maybe add another condition about filenmae to your CamlQuery...
**CamlBuilder** is invaluable tool for creating those queries.

Comment: thanks again. It now makes sense why the same image was showing up more then once. Thank you! With regards to the CamlQuery, the issue I am having is I can't seem to figure out how to bind the query to a FileCollection (_fileCollection). I can bind CamlQuery to a ListCollection easy enough with .GetItems(camlQuery). But, basically I don't know how to filter the FileCollection. That's where I thought LINQ would come in but I have no idea how to go about using LINQ. Or is there some other trick I am missing?

Comment: Well, I think we are getting to the point! :) Even if you need to work with files from the library, you can work with them as `ListItem`s first. So instead of getting `imageList.RootFolder.Files`, you can get the items in standart way and filter it using `CamlQuery`. After you retrieve items you need, just access the `item.File` property on each item. There you will find info you need (url).

Comment: Thanks again for your reply jumbo...I have not forgotten about this just haven't had time to try out your solution. Will get round to it soon though. Cheers